# How to create a simple circular array?

Tags: algorithm, queue, implementation, abstract-data-type

According to my textbook, realizations of Queue ADT can be done:

- Using circular arrays
- Using linked lists

How do you create a simple circular array? I'm not sure if it's widely used. Is it just a linked list where the last item points back to the first item?

Comment: Basically it is an array with a pointer to the first element, container capacity and current size.

Comment: Just to toss my two cents in, a linked list where the last element points back to the first is a circular linked list.

Comment: Yes, circular buffers are widely used. Many applications that rely on fixed-length queues implement them with circular buffers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several examples of ring buffers and design tradeoffs associated with them on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

The simplest example would in TypeScript be:

```ts
class RingBuffer<T> {
  private backing: Array<T>;
  private size: number;
  private start: number;
  get length(): number {
    return this.size;
  }
  constructor(private maxSize: number) {
    this.backing = [];
    this.start = 0;
    this.size = 0;
  }
  public push(...ts: Array<T>): number {
    if (this.size + ts.length > this.maxSize) {
      throw new Error('Ring overflow error.');
    }
    for (const t of ts) {
      this.backing[(this.start + this.size) % this.maxSize] = t;
      this.size++;
    }
    return this.size;
  }
  public shift() {
    if (this.size === 0) {
      throw new Error('No such element.');
    }
    this.size--;
    const val = this.backing[this.start];
    this.start = (this.start + 1) % this.maxSize;
    return val;
  }
  public pop() {
    if (this.size === 0) {
      throw new Error('No such element.');
    }
    this.size--;
    return this.backing[(this.start + this.size) % this.maxSize];
  }
}
```

The basic idea is that it is a fixed-size array which uses a little bit of pointer math to loop back around to the beginning as you try to fill it up more and more; it may or may not do bounds checking the way that the above does.

Answer (score 0):

For Java *(and similar in many other languages)*, there are 2 choices:

- Fixed size, with `Object[]` as internal storage.
  Methods: `size()` / `rotate()` / `get(index)` / `set(index, value)`
- Flexible size, with `ArrayList<T>` as internal storage.
  In additional to what fixed size version can do, it also could `add(value)` / `add(index, value)` / `remove(index)` / `remove(value)` / `indexOf(index)` / `lastIndexOf(index)`.

Tips:

- `Linked list` is not a good choice, due to slow accessing elements via index.
- Both choices use a `int head` to point to the circular index.
  Need to maintain it, and convert between it and  the internal structure's real index in various operations.